# service.CreateAsync() always returns Id as 0 in ABP

Tags: abp, aspnetzero

I'm using generated entities from ABP Suite. Sometimes I need `Id` of inserted entity. But when `CreateAsync` method is called it returns 0. It internally calls `InsertAsync` and not `InsertAndGetIdAsync`. So is there any way to map Id from saved entity?

Here's the code:

```cs
   [Authorize(BrianPermissions.LabRequirements.Create)]
   public virtual async Task<LabRequirementDto> CreateAsync(
        LabRequirementCreateDto input)
   {
        var LabRequirement = await _LabRequirementManager.CreateAsync(
         input.TechQualification, 
         input.TechExperience, 
         input.Equipments, 
         input.Others);
       UnitOfWorkManager.Current.SaveChangesAsync();

       return ObjectMapper.Map<LabRequirement, LabRequirementDto>(LabRequirement);
   }
```

Comment: Would you please share your code?

Comment: Try using `SaveChangesAsync()` after insert

Comment: @AhmadMasoum I tried with SaveChangesAsync() but still Id is returned as 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forget 'await' keyword in your code:

```cs
  await UnitOfWorkManager.Current.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Can you try again ?

See: https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Unit-Of-Work#savechangesasync